# Unexpected UnavailableException in a Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

- I have a 3-node C* cluster.
- C* client has read consistency level set to QUORUM.
- When one node in cluster is down I am getting an UnavailableException in response to a read query

**Why?** Quorum for cluster consisting of 3 nodes is 2, so it should handle outage of one node.

A few more details:

Cassandra version:

```
ReleaseVersion: 1.1.6
```

Configuration of keyspace and column family:

```
Keyspace: QuestionAnswerService:
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy
  Durable Writes: true
    Options: [datacenter1:2]
  Column Families:
  //...
  ColumnFamily: answersByQuestion
      Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
      GC grace seconds: 864000
      Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
      Read repair chance: 1.0
      DC Local Read repair chance: 0.0
      Populate IO Cache on flush: false
      Replicate on write: true
      Caching: KEYS_ONLY
      Bloom Filter FP chance: default
      Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
      Compression Options:
        sstable_compression: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor
  //...
```

Exception thrown during a read query when one node is down:

```
2013-05-21 17:43:37 ERROR CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:81 - com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=cassandra.xxx.yyy(10.33.0.53):9160, latency=56(56), attempts=1]UnavailableException()
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TokenRangeOfflineException: TokenRangeOfflineException: [host=cassandra.xxx.yyy(10.33.0.53):9160, latency=56(56), attempts=1]UnavailableException()
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:165)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:198)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:190)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:248)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:188)
    at org.example.Casstest$delayedInit$body.apply(Casstest.scala:66)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)
    at org.example.Casstest$.main(Casstest.scala:14)
    at org.example.Casstest.main(Casstest.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:7288)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_slice(Cassandra.java:552)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_slice(Cassandra.java:536)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:203)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$1$2.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:190)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:55)
    ... 22 more
```

Code in Scala which reproduces the above error:

```
package org.example

import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.{CountingConnectionPoolMonitor, ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl}
import com.netflix.astyanax.{Keyspace, AstyanaxContext}
import com.netflix.astyanax.impl.AstyanaxConfigurationImpl
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.NodeDiscoveryType
import com.netflix.astyanax.retry.ConstantBackoff
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.{ColumnFamily, ConsistencyLevel}
import com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftFamilyFactory
import com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.StringSerializer
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Casstest extends App {

  println("Hello, cass-test")

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Casstest.getClass)

  val clusterName = "Cassandra"
  val hostname = "cassandra.xxx.yyy"
  val port = 9160
  val thriftSocketTimeout = 4000
  val keyspaceName = "QuestionAnswerService"
  val timeout = 5000

  val connectionPool = new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("ConnectionPool")
    .setPort(port)
    //    .setMaxConnsPerHost(1)
    .setSeeds(hostname + ":" + port)
    .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
    .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
    .setTimeoutWindow(timeout)

  val cassandraContext: AstyanaxContext[Keyspace] =
    new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
      .forCluster(clusterName)
      .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
      .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.TOKEN_AWARE)
      .setRetryPolicy(new ConstantBackoff(timeout, 10000))
      .setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_QUORUM))
      .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(connectionPool)
      .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
      .forKeyspace(keyspaceName)
      .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance())

  cassandraContext.start()

  val keyspace: Keyspace = cassandraContext.getEntity()

  val answersByQuestionCf = new ColumnFamily[String, String](
    "answersByQuestion", // Column Family Name
    StringSerializer.get(), // Key Serializer
    StringSerializer.get(), // Column Serializer
    StringSerializer.get()) // Value Serializer

  while(true) {

    logger.info("query start")

    val result = keyspace
      .prepareQuery(answersByQuestionCf)
      .getKey("birthyear")
      .execute()

    logger.info("query finished: " + result.toString)

    result.getResult.getColumnNames.take(10) foreach {
      logger.info
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Are all your nodes in datacenter1?  Can you read and write through cassandra-cli?

Comment: Yes. What's more, I just found out that increasing replication factor to 3 solves the problem - I could succesfuly make queries with one node down. 
However, according to documentation it should not make the difference. For RF = 2 and also for RF = 3 QUORUM = 2
Link: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/data_consistency [About Read Consistency]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of nodes required by the consistency level is a function of the replication factor, not the number of nodes in the cluster.  So for RF=2, a quorum is 2 so all your nodes must be up to be able to read all your data.

With 3 nodes in your cluster, RF=2 and reading at CL.QUORUM, you can only access 1/3 of your data with one node down.  Reads for other keys will result in an unavailable exception.

With 3 nodes in your cluster, RF=3 and reading at CL.QUORUM, you can still access all your data with one node down.